# React and dynamic src of audio html5

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i have a problem with dymanic src  for the tag audio in React project.
If a insert the src  manually work. What is the problem?

```
  {this.state.videos.map((item,key)=>
      <div class="column is-4" key={key}>
        <div class="card has-text-centered">
          {item.snippet.title}
          <hr/>
            {item.snippet.description}
            <hr/>      
            <audio controls>
             <source src={item.mp3} />
           </audio>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: must be the `item.mp3`..show us the `item` object

Comment: the values of item.mp3 is a string, the same string that i  try to insert manually and worked

Comment: I resolve putting placeholder src